# Matrices of Lie algebra of Dynkin diagram B2

Tags: lie-algebras

The Lie algebra $so_5$ has 10 elements and its root structure is given by the Dynkin diagram B2. I have been having trouble creating an explicit $5 \times 5$ complex matrix representation of its 10 elements from its Cartan matrix. I would greatly appreciate help with this.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question.  Why would you expect the Cartan matrix to give you a particular matrix representation?  The Cartan matrix gives you the structure of the Lie algebra using the Serre relations.  This is explained in a variety of places, e.g., Humphrey's book on Lie algebras and representation theory.
$$ $$
The compact real form of the Lie algebra of type B2 is the algebra of skewsymmetric endomorphisms of a five-dimensional euclidean space.  It doesn't get any more explicit than that: just take the 5x5 skewsymmetric matrices.


Comment: The question is: what are the matrices corresponding to the Chevalley generators, i.e. the famous (e_i,f_i,h_i)?


Comment: @Guntram: that's also not a research-level question, Allen's answer notwithstanding.  See his answer for how to go about it.  In any case, you don't get this from the Cartan matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I have found this answer helpful. Also, I have just discovered the book, "Notes on Lie Algebras" by Hans Samelson, which has clarified the issue.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not sure this question is appropriate for this site, here goes.

First, you need a maximal torus. Inside SO(5) we have SO(4) and then SO(2) x SO(2).

Write your antisymmetric matrices as

$$\begin{matrix}
aJ & C & v 
\end{matrix} $$
$$\begin{matrix}
-C^T & bJ & w 
\end{matrix} $$
$$\begin{matrix}
-v^T & -w^T & 0 
\end{matrix} $$
where
$J = \left( {0\atop -1}{1\atop 0} \right) $, $C$ is square, and $v$ and $w$ are columns. Then the $a$ and $b$ parts are the torus, the $v$ gets you the $\pm x_1$ weights, the $w$ gets you the $\pm x_2$, and the $C$ gets you the $\pm x_1\pm x_2$.

Taking $x_1$ and $x_2 - x_1$ as simple roots, the $e_{x_1}$ is
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&i\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
-1&-i&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
and the $e_{x_2-x_1}$ is
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&i&0\\
0&0&i&-1&0\\
-1&-i&0&0&0\\
-i&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}